# Identifying a Raspberry Pi host with configure

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, configure, host, autotools

I work on a cross-platform project, and recently added support for the Raspberry Pi. The project, to make sure it is available at as wide as possible audience, has a premake, a cmake and an autotools build system. I have set up cross-compilation for the RPi, and everything works great.

Recently, I also set up a Raspberry Pi VM (Until I get a real RPi) trying to build the library. From Linux, I run './configure --host=arm-raspberry-linux-gnueabihf', and configure takes it from there. On the RPi however (Rasbian 7), the default host found by config.guess is 'armv61-unknown-linux-gnueabihf'. For that reason, even natively on the Pi, I have to run './configure --host=arm-raspberry-linux-gnueabihf'. So, my question sums up to this:

Currently, I currently have something like this in my configure script:

```
case "$host" in
    armv61-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)
        if [[ -f /usr/bin/rpi-update ]]; then
            on_raspberry=yes
        fi
    ;;
    ## other hosts here
esac
```

So, my question sums up to this:

1. Is 'armv61-unknown-linux-gnueabihf' only reported on the Raspberry Pi? If not, how can configure make sure that it is really on RPi? Is checking for rpi-update sufficient? Do different distros (Arch Linux, Pidora, ...) also have rpi-update?
2. Are there any other possible host triplets like this that are reported by different versions of the Pi?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of logic do you have for `./configure --build=...`?  What is the default build reported by the RPi?

Comment: No special handling for `--build=...`. I thought that `--host=...` was enough. What more could `--build` offer me??

Comment: `--build` describes the [system on which you are building](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html).  So the test for `rpi-update` is really only valid there.  `--host` describes the system for where the built programs and libs will run (e.g. cross-compilation).  You really should use [both if `--host` is used](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Hosts-and-Cross_002dCompilation.html)

Comment: I don't get it. Why specify --build or --host ?? Cross compilation is not the problem. My problem is about building in the rpi

Comment: Alright.  Are you invoking the [`AC_CANONICAL_BUILD`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Canonicalizing.html#Canonicalizing) macro in `configure.ac`?  Is there code in `configure.ac` like `case "$build" in ... esac`?

Comment: No. But I think we both don't understand what the other is trying to say. I want configure to check whether it's running on an RPi. Since config.guess reports 'armv61-unknown-linux-gnueabihf', I can't be sure that this is an RPi, because 'armv61-unknown-linux-gnueabihf' may be reported by a random arm linux distro. For that reason, I am looking for an extra test, like searching some file in /proc, or using uname, or /etc/lsd_release or /etc/os-release. None of these clarify that the system is a Raspberry Pi. Is there anything else like these?

Comment: No, @user2500758, I understand what you want, and have provided source in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is 'armv61-unknown-linux-gnueabihf' only reported on the Raspberry Pi?

Other platforms could use that as well.

> If not, how can configure make sure that it is really on RPi?

It can't really (e.g. running it on a RPi VM).  `configure` is just a shell script.

> Is checking for rpi-update sufficient?

See above.

> Do different distros (Arch Linux, Pidora, ...) also have rpi-update?

Current Pidora and Arch images don't have `/usr/bin/rpi-update`.  Neither does old Rasbpian images at least as far back as 10 Aug 2012.

> Are there any other possible host triplets like this that are reported by different versions of the Pi?

[There are 3 triplets for the RPi cross compilers](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708), so it would not be surprising if there were others.

**EDIT**: so basically what is wanted is a way for `configure` to detect when it's building on a Raspberry Pi.  Easy as pie:

**configure.ac**

```
# need to detect build...
AC_CANONICAL_BUILD

...

AC_MSG_CHECKING([if build is on Raspberry Pi])
# The test for 'BCM2708' might be sufficient,
# but the presence of Serial is definitely part of
# the Pi firmware for codec licensing.
# See this thread
# <http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.phpf=29&t=28304&p=252357#p251536>.
AS_CASE("$build",
     [arm*-*-linux*],
     [on_rpi=`awk -v r=0 '/^Hardware@<:@ \t@:>@+:@<:@ \t@:>@+BCM2708/ { ++r;} /^Serial@<:@ \t@:>@+:/ { ++r; } END { print ((r > 1) ? "yes" : "no");}' /proc/cpuinfo`],
     [on_rpi="no"])
AC_MSG_RESULT($on_rpi)
```

Detects on Raspbian, Pidora, should work on Arch.  Arch doesn't seem to include a compiler in its current install image, so `configure` failed when I tried it.  All detected build as `armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` when running `./configure`.  I have not tried this on any kind of RPi emulator or VM.

Comment: Actually, what I want is searching for a file that only exists on Raspberry Pi. Something like uname. I tried with /etc/os-release and /etc/lsb_release, but these do not clearly state that the system is a Raspberry Pi (the only contain rasbian-specific info). And that led me to 'rpi-update'

Comment: Since all triplet variants establish the OS as some kind of "linux" or "linux-gnueabi" that would make inspecting `/proc/cpuinfo` [described here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/checking-your-raspberry-pi-board-version/) or other Linux-y hardware stuff in `/proc` valid.  This should be portable across all RPi distros.

Comment: And as with `rpi-update` it would be tested in `--build`.  You'd also want to check for "arm" CPUs in addition to "linux" OS.

Comment: It should be noted that RPi2 has a BCM2709 rather than a BCM2708 so they can be differentiated between

Answer (score 0):

BCM2708 in /proc/cpuinfo might be unique for RPi.

```
From File /proc/cpuinfo

Processor       : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 697.95
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2708
Revision        : 000d
Serial          : 00000000db690cb4
```

Comment: A quick google search only showed pages regarding the RPi, so I guess you're right. Thank you very much!